# Boost, Lib C++ and Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, boost

Does anyone know where I can get a easy to build version of Boost with Lib C++ for iOS ?

I've tried Boost Framework and it didn't like my project as its in C++ 11. I've tried Boost-iOS but it didn't want to compile. It wasn't happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build boost library using this [a-coding xcode project](https://github.com/aleph7/a-coding). it worked for me, managed to build 1.44 boost c++ with this tool.

also this updated verion of [boostoniphone](https://gitorious.org/~galbraithjoseph/boostoniphone/galbraithjosephs-boostoniphone) allows to create a library using the most recent version.

Comment: Cheers :) Been a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

ofxiOSBoost: Boost 1.57.0 - iOS - libc++

See: https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost

- arm64, armv7, i386, x86_64` Boost 1.57.0 or 1.56.0 libc++ / std=c++11
- Makefile scripts to build yourself (very easily)
- Can build in libstdc++ or libc++
- Multiple releases